# Current section indicator - HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create a section indicator like in the image, that will highlight what is the current section that is shown on the screen. Now can someone help me create the mockup for this in htm and css(no need for js for now)

[image]

Comment: You mean like this right:  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/ (right side of page as you scroll)

Comment: You need js for this.

Comment: @Deryck yap that's the functionality, but I need help with the mockup. How can I design this

Comment: @Anubhav I know - I need help with the mockup (html,css)

Comment: You actually might be able to do this without any JS if the user is clicking all the way down the page.  This is more of a project to be worked on than it is a specific question about CSS or HTML.  You may be better off checking the chat rooms here for someone to spend some time teaching you.  Lots of helpful people there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this blog post: http://blog.sathomas.me/post/tracking-progress-in-pure-css

You don't necessarily need JavaScript